# Azure KeyVault: Exceptions when using GetSecretAsync

Tags: azure-keyvault

In development mode, on my local machine VS2017 15.7.5, I'm using

- Asp.Net MVC Core 2.1
- Azure KeyVault 3.0.0
- AppAuthentication 1.1.0-preview

I've built a separate project used to get secrets from the vault, adding logging and other stuff.  I reference that project from my MVC project.

When I launch the site I get:

`Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll`

Which I can't track down.

{EDIT: I found this, it as a bad reference in the `CSPROJ`. Everything else remains the same.}

I instantiate a `AzureServiceTokenProvider` like this:

```
_provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
_client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient
                 .AuthenticationCallback(_provider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
```

and then I use it like this:

```
try
    {
        var secretBundle = await _client
           .GetSecretAsync(_config[$"{SecretUrlsKey}:{secretName}"])
           .ConfigureAwait(false);

        Debug.WriteLine("Secret retrieved from vault ...");

        _secretCache.Add(secretName, secretBundle.Value);
        return secretBundle?.Value;
     }
catch (Exception e)
...
```

I then I get a flurry of errors (none of which are returned to my code).  Like these:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.HttpRequestWithStatusException' in Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.HttpRequestWithStatusException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException' in Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Eventually I get the value I'm looking for, but this seems a little wonky.

FWIW, I have had zero success deploying it to Azure.

Anyone have any ideas about any of this?

TIA

Comment: I forgot to mention how I fixed the file not found problem.  Do this:`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional
gacutil -if Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll`

Answer (score 0):

As for the second problem, it happened to me on two different machines.  With no real scientific analysis (no time for that) my hunch is that the dotnet core update that allows you to run VS while it installs is causing the problem.

In the end, I used the `Visual Studio Installer` repair option and the problem went away.  Something must have been corrupted.

Don't forget to backup your extensions and settings, cause the repair will nuke all that.

Nuget package clearing and reinstalling did nothing.